# c# string.split works only a few times

Tags: c#, string, split, serial-port

I must split a string received via serial port.
I receive a string like "JMT#HB00001#4563.32#N#1234.22#E$" each second. First of all I display the received line on a TextBox as a proof of what I got.

I then try to split the string using a character from another TextBox. I show which character I use on a label (tbSep.Text[0]), how many substrings I get on another and the resulting strings.

```
if((datapacket != null))
{
      Array.Clear(datapacket, 0, datapacket.Length);
}

char xsep = tbSep.Text[0];

ComTestBox.AppendText(dataIn);

if(xsep != null)
{
   datapacket = dataIn.Split(xsep);
   lseparator.Text = xsep.ToString();
}
else
{
   datapacket = dataIn.Split(null);
   lseparator.Text = "BS";
}
int1 = datapacket.Length;
lpackets.Text = int1.ToString();
```

The received string is correctly displayed on the ComTestBox textbox. I see the chosen separator character in the label lseparator (#).

But when I check lpackets value, sometimes I get a 1 and sometimes a 6 (obviously I get data only when it is 6).

I cannot understand why a correct dataIn string is not splitted correctly each time. Could someone please give me a hint?
xsep is a '#', and in any case lseparator label becomes BS... so it seems it uses the right character for the split.

If I check in Visual Studio, that's what I get when I hover on:
dataIn = "JMT#HB00001#4563.32#N#1234.22#E$\r\n"

xsep = 35 '#'

xsep != null = true

datapacket = {string}
[0] = null

Comment: `xsep` is a `char`. It cannot and will not ever be `null`. It *could* be `\0` but that's not the same thing. Also `String.Split(null)` splits on whitespace (but you'd never hit that line)

Comment: Is this all happening in an event handler? If so, did you declare `datapacket` outside of the method (ie as a class level field)? If the handler is getting invoked quick enough and the variable is actually a field, re-entry of the method is likely clearing your array (since it's not null and you clear it in that case) and the ordering of things is just not apparent to you. Use a local variable instead to store the result of the split and see if that changes the observed behavior. You might need to throw a lock around everything to prevent concurrent access.. But just throwing out guesses

Comment: Ok, I was trying to identify an empty char, and I found that somewhere, I should check my browser history. String.Split(null) should work if the char is empty (I read that writing ' ' is not accepted).
dataoacket is declared inside "public partial class com_setup : Form" as a "public string[]", meanwhile I have a "serialPort1_DataReceiver()" that gets "ReadExisting()" content and invokes "this.Invoke(new EventHandler(ShowData));" where the code above lies :/

Comment: I tried also with local variables and splitting with a two character string, but it keeps splitting the string inconsistently. One time it gets a correctly set of substring, the other times it gets one result only.